# How do I run F# Interactive on a more recent version of the framework?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

.NET 4.6.2 and later enable the use of the `\\?\` syntax to [access long file paths on Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/21/more-on-new-net-path-handling/), but F# Interactive seems only to boot using .NET 4.5.

I've tried `--noframework` and then `#r`ing `v4.7.1\mscorlib.dll` as well as the various `--targetprofile:netcore`, both running FSI.exe from within Visual Studio 2017 as well as running it from the command line, and neither seems to work.

Am I missing something? Is there no way to get F# Interactive to use a more recent version of the framework?

Comment: What code are you trying to run in FSI using `\\?\`?

Comment: @AMieres Just trying to open a file using System.IO.File.OpenRead that has a really long path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not until VS 2019 is released. For VS 2017, FSI is based on .NET Framework 4.6.

We could theoretically bump that up to 4.6.1, but because 4.6.1 is the base .NET Framework version that VS 2017depends on, we can't go any higher in VS 2017.

Doing so would then make the F# tools carry an implicit dependency on a higher version of .NET Framework than what VS 2017 installs by default, forcing anyone who installs a .NET workload to also install that higher version of the framework. For some users, this would mean a machine restart. Yikes!

Comment: Does this mean that I should always expect the FSI version to be as much as several years behind?

Comment: For VS 2017, yes. It is unlikely that it will change. Starting with VS 2019, we'll bump this up to a minimum version that is guaranteed to be on someone's machine with the VS installation.